# PHP I am getting an error with this code

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

```
$mysql = mysql_query("SELECT pass, user, id, folder, http, spacelimit, language, theme, permbrowse, permupload, permcreate, permuser, permadmin, permdelete, permmove, permchmod, permget, permdeleteuser, permedituser, permmakeuser, permpass, permrename, permedit, permsub, formatperm, status, recycle, permprefs FROM ".$GLOBALS['config']['db']['pref']."users WHERE user='".mysql_real_escape_string($user)."'");
    list ($dbpass, $dbuser, $userid, $userdir, $http, $limit, $language, $theme, $permbrowse, $permupload, $permcreate, $permuser, $permadmin, $permdelete, $permmove, $permchmod, $permget, $permdeleteuser, $permedituser, $permmakeuser, $permpass, $permrename, $permedit, $permsub, $formatperm, $status, $recycle, $permprefs) = mysql_fetch_row($mysql);
```

The error is on the 3rd line. It says

> Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
>   given in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 83

I tried looking it up and I'm having trouble finding a fix.

I know that some of the methods have been deprecated but I'm just trying to fix this so I can get it 2 work (for now). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It may not help answer your question (and I know you mention that you're aware of this in your question - this is for people who stumble on this question who aren't aware), but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Comment: Make sure that there are no errors when the query executes. That would cause `$result` to be set as "not a mysql resource".

Comment: @Matt Last thing on the last line all the way to the right.

Comment: @Florin I just noticed and removed my comment.

Comment: `echo` out the query and verify that it's valid.

Comment: Try using `echo mysql_error()` after the query to see why it's failing.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running `mysql_query(mysql_query(...))`.

```
$mysql = "SELECT pass, user, id, folder, http, spacelimit, language, theme, permbrowse, permupload, permcreate, permuser, permadmin, permdelete, permmove, permchmod, permget, permdeleteuser, permedituser, permmakeuser, permpass, permrename, permedit, permsub, formatperm, status, recycle, permprefs FROM ".$GLOBALS['config']['db']['pref']."users WHERE user='".mysql_real_escape_string($user)."'"; 

echo $mysql; // Get the output here and run it directly to see if it succeeds

$result = mysql_query($mysql) or die(mysql_error()); // add `or die(mysql_error())` to output an error if the query fails
```

Comment: Good point. Updated code and same result

Comment: Nice catch! I didn't even notice!

Comment: It's always best to add in some type of exception handling for debugging purposes.  The simplest way is to use: `or die(mysql_error())` to output an error if the query fails.

Answer (score 0):

Read the [documentation for mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)!  It will return FALSE if the query failed for any reason.  You can use [mysql_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) to figure out what the reason was.

Comment: Actually it will return false if the query fails ***for any reason***.

Comment: how do we find out why it failed?

Comment: @CocoaDev: turn on your warnings and errors on-screen, you should get a warning.

Comment: You have to `echo mysql_error()` after the query OR use `mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error())`.

Comment: @Matt, Absolutely correct, my bad.

Comment: That's my -1; if you update the answer I'll take it down.

Comment: What you need to do is get rid of `mysql_*` but that's my (and about every other PHP expert's) opinion.

Comment: @Matt Done, with a little more info.